# VB.NET: CryptographicException ("Bad Data") not being caught

Tags: .net, vb.net

I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx) walkthrough for encoding and decoding data. When using the wrong key to decode, the CryptoStream class throws a CryptographicException. I was unable to copy the code, because VS froze when stopping execution, but here's a screenshot.

[image]

According to an answer to a similar question, the problem is supposedly that the exception was thrown outside the Try-Catch block, so I expanded it to encompass all the code in the method. Still, the exception is not caught. The MsgBox("Hei") is never shown. Clicking 'continue' results in the exception being thrown over and over. The program shouldn't break, according to my exception settings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Run it in release mode and you'll see the expected behavior.  That's a ... weirdness in visual studio.  Experienced it many times.  Don't know exactly why it won't stop halting execution while debugging.  If I were to guess, it's rolling the callstack back and stopping at every level, but I have no reason to believe this is the real cause, only that I once mashed the continue button a bunch of times and it actually continued after awhile.  Another alternative is to find the exception in the Exception Settings and make sure it is deselected...

Comment: Try to start with CTRL + F5. With CTRL you don't attach the debugger.

Comment: Running it in release mode didn't help. Starting with CTRL + F5 did. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with CTRL + F5 fixed the problem.